# Pull Rows for New Dataframe from Existing Dataframe python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Looking for a convenient way to store off certain rows of a dataframe into a new dataframe if the row matches some external criteria.

I have a dataframe (df) which contains records that I'm running against an internal database. Sometimes the query works, and sometimes it doesn't. I'd like the store the rows that cause exceptions. The new dataframe should have the same structure as the original one. I've been testing different solutions all morning, but nothing quite seems to work. My current code looks something like this:

```
    cols=['recordID','linkID','date']
    dfNew = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols)    

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        try:
            updateStatement = """
            EXEC dbo.storedProc
                @recordID = {0},
                @linkID = {1},
                @date = '{2}',
            """.format(row.recordID, row.LinkID, row.date)       
            cursor.execute(updateStatement)

        except Exception as e:
            lst = ({'recordID':row.recordID,'linkID':row.linkID,'date':row.date})
            dfexcept = dfexcept.append(lst, ignore_index=True)
```

In my current situation, it gives me a table that has values (functions such as 'print()' and 'len()' return expected results) but functions specific to Dataframes (merge(), .head()) don't work, and when asked to return 'dfexcept' it says 'empty DataFrame'.

So, in short, I know something is wrong, but not what. I'm trying to store off rows that throw exceptions, but I suspect the way I'm building the DataFrame is giving me issues (I thought building a dictionary list was odd, but it got me closest to desired behavior and was suggested elsewhere).

How do I store off rows into a new DataFrame (normally)? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use a slicing technique , where you can slice the row that you need and put it in another dataframe . Syntax is shown below

Df_new = Df_old.iloc['starting_name_of_row':'ending_name_of_row']